# What is the best method for streaming BBC iPlayer live audio content through my website

Tags: php, video-streaming, audio-streaming, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm about to push live a client site for a football club I am about to push live.

The site is looking/working brilliantly, with the exception of live audio/media streaming.

What I need to do is broadcast the match commentary from our site. Match commentary is usually broadcast from BBC radio.

Any advice/guidance on this would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: This question is too broad and too unspecific. You need to do proper research and try something. if you then get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us what you've tried and what happens and we can take it from there.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the feedback. The issue I have is that I need to broadcast match commentary from BBC Radio 5L through my website. As I understand it, BBC match commentator turns up at the football ground and then plugs into the clubs ISDN2 switch. How do I then take this data and stream it through the client's website?

Comment: I don't work for BBC, so I have no idea. But like I said, this question is too broad. You should contact BBC and ask them. How knows, they might have an API for it, or they might have a restriction that says that you're not allowed to do what you want. SO is for _specific programming_ questions and when posting, you need to have done the proper research and made an attempt. We can help you with your _code_ if it isn't working. It's not a general IT support for services on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy ways of approaching this, you can either:

- Use an iframe which will directly link to the BBC radio broadcast (which is the ugliest and worst way of handling this).
- Look into direct integration methods which BBC or other radio streamers may offer, such as API access, for more information: http://www.bbc.co.uk/developer/technology/apis.html